# How to ingest to kusto from local file with authentication through manage identity

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Does manage identity auth support ingesting local csv file to Kusto? If it does, is there any sample code that you can refer me to?

If it doesn't, does subject name and issue certificate auth support ingest in Kusto from local file? if it does, Is there any sample code that can help me figure out how to authenticate to Kusto with ApplicationCertificateBlob and ingest local file to Kusto? While I was testing the below code to authenticate with ApplicationCertificateBlob I got an error which says that Application Key is missing in connection string which I am not sure what Application Key is and why it's needed to auth with ApplicationCertificateBlob.

> new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(string.Format(KustoConnectionString, clusterName, dbName))
> {
> FederatedSecurity = true,
> ApplicationClientId = clientId,
> Authority = tenantId,
> ApplicationCertificateBlob = certificate,
> ApplicationCertificateSendX5c = true
> };

Answer (score 0):

> How to ingest to kusto from local file with authentication through manage identity

Below is one of the approach to ingest `.csv` file from local file to `kusto` table you can follow the below steps:

- Store the `.csv` file into the Azure storage account. In my case i stored in Azure Blob Storage as you can see below:
  [image]
- Make `Allow Blob anonymous access` to `Enabled` and change access level to `Container` as shown below:
  [image]
- As the data must be ingested into kusto by using Managed Identity, make sure to provide `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role to that respective Managed Identity as shown below:
  [image]

Try below query to ingest data into kusto table:

```sql
.ingest into table <TableName> ('https://<StorageName>.blob.core.windows.net/adxcont/sampleFile.csv;managed_identity=*****')
```

**Output:**
[image]